# html images are showing up in localhost as the broken image icon

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, image, png

I have included an image in my html, the image is saved locally in my files, the img src path is correct, I have tried including the whole file path from 'C:/Users' in the img src but nothing works. It just shows up with the broken image icon. 
I am working in python/Visual studio code/bootstrap.
Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Complete Bootstrap 4 Website Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>


</div>
</nav>
```

and here is a screenshot of the folder directory:

[image]

I feel like I've tried everything, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...working with python... in what way are you working with python? flask/django etc? unless yo u tell us this we probably won't be able to help.

Comment: also you have your images directory in your templates directory which is not `img/logo.png` but `templates/img/logo.png`

Comment: Sorry yeah I'm working with flask. I've tried with the templates/img/logo.png and it doesn't work. I've tried moving the img folder out into the bootstrap 4 site files folder, still does nothing.

Comment: you put images in the static directory and use `<img src="url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')">`

Comment: have you reaad the docs? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files. and directory organization is important http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/organizing.html#package

Comment: like this? <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><url_for('static', logo='img/logo.png')></a>


</div>
</nav>

Comment: or do I not need the href?

Comment: you still need the `img` tag, the `href="#"` should be whatever you want to link that image to, usually this would be the home page. So whatever your home page function is called you would use that function name in the `url_for` for that link so if your home page function is called `def index()` you need to.. e.g: `<!-- Navigation --> <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top"> <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="url_for('index')"><img src="url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')"></a> </div> </nav>`

Comment: the `url_for` function returns a path to such so `url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')` becomes `static/img/logo.png`and `url_for('index')` returns whatever your `def index` function does (goes to homepage)

Comment: having said all that you can just 'hardcode' the img urls if you wish, so relative to your main app file you can just, in your case, do `<img src="templates/img/logo.png">` and that should work, again I highly recommend reading the docs for flask they are very goo and easy to understand.

Comment: Your way almost worked but I needed curly braces <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('hello_world')}}"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}"></a>


 </a>


</div>
</nav>

Comment: thanks though very helpful

Comment: ohh yeah, doh! sorry its been a little while since i used jinja templating and it just skipped my mind lol glad your sorted